# Sort multidimensional array with usort by children

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array, usort

I'm working within the CakePHP framework, and have the following multidimensional array that I will need to sort by values. I'm using `usort`, but cannot figure out how to sort by the children of `[ForumPost]`.

Here's the array:

```
Array
( 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ForumPost] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 174
                    [forum_id] => 81
                    [user_id] => 39
                    [title] => A test post
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ForumPost] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 64
                    [forum_id] => 208
                    [user_id] => 36
                    [title] => B test post
... etc
```

My function and call are:

```
usort($array, array("ForumSearchesController", "cmp"));

function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a['ForumPost']['title'] - $b['ForumPost']['title'];
}
```

Comment: Instead of `$a['ForumPost']['title'] - $b['ForumPost']['title']` it looks like you just need to `return strcmp($a['ForumPost']['title'], $b['ForumPost']['title']);`

Comment: Given that title is a string, why are you using minus for your comparison?

Comment: Look at Example 3 on the php usort page http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Haha, that makes total sense. Not sure what I was thinking. Thanks friends. You make StackOverflow the greatest site on the Internet.

Comment: Is there any way to pass another variable to `cmp()` to determine the sort? I.e. to make `'title'` dynamic instead of static.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I used `$args = array('node' => 'ForumPost', 'sort' => 'title');
     usort($dataForumPost, function($a, $b) use($args) {
      return strcmp($a[$args['node']][$args['sort']], $b[$args['node']][$args['sort']]);
     });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply subtract titles (strings) from each other and expect a meaningful result. The equivalent for strings is calling the function [`strcmp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['ForumPost']['title'], $b['ForumPost']['title']);
}
```

Comment: Haha, that makes total sense. Not sure what I was thinking. Thanks friend. You all make StackOverflow the greatest site on the Internet.